# how do I find an angle of an isosceles triangle when it is next to a parallelogram?

Tags: triangles

$ABCD$ is a parallelogram.
$\triangle CDE$ is an isosceles triangle.
$\angle DAB \text{ is } 64^°$. Work out the size of the $\angle DEC$.

[image]

Comment: Is $ADE$ a line?

Answer (score 0):

By the proprieties of parallelogram, we have: $$\angle BAD=\angle CDE$$  Now because $CDE$ is isoscele, we have: $$\angle CED=180°-2\cdot \angle CDE = 180°-2\cdot64°=52°°$$